# Filtering values of attributes in JSON using camel and rerouting of endpoints

Tags: json, filter, apache-camel, uri

I have a JSON object and I would like to filter the value of a particular value using Camel.

This is an example attribute of my JSON object:

```
{
  Animals: Water/Fish  
}
```

There are other possible values such as Land/Horse and I would like to filter the values by the types(For eg, Water, Land etc) and the routing of the endpoints is based on these types.

Currently, the routing on my XML file looks like this:

```
<route>
<description>Example </description>
<from uri="testing:resource.A" />


<to uri="ref:specFile"/>
<to uri="testing.transformed.Result">
</route>
```

How do I filter the Animal types? Specifically, how do I get the values before the "/"?

Comment: Take a look at jsonpath: http://camel.apache.org/jsonpath

Comment: You may find inspiration in this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715654/how-to-extract-substring-in-json-path-using-camel